# Sum of squares compared to square of sum, divided by number of elements being summed

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

Let $M, S > 0$ such that $M < S$, where $M$ is a positive integer and $S = \sum_{k = 1}^{M} a_k$, and each $a_k$ is a positive integer. Is it always the case that $\frac{S^2}{M} = \frac{\big(\sum_{k = 1}^{M} a_k\big)^2}{M} \leq \sum_{k = 1}^{M} a_k^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claimed identity may be rearranged as $\frac1M\sum_{k=1}^Ma_k\le\sqrt{\frac{\sum_ka_k^2}{M}}$. This is called the [RMS-AM inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality) or [QM-AM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities). It's equivalent to the fact that the variance of the $a_k$ is non-negative.